# sum sql with differents columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table as:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE
(
    ID          BIGINT(20),
    REPORTED_0      INTEGER(11),
    REPORTED_1      INTEGER(11),
    REPORTED_2      INTEGER(11),
    REPORTED_3      INTEGER(11),
    REPORTED_4      INTEGER(11),
    REPORTED_5      INTEGER(11),
    REPORTED_6      INTEGER(11),
    REPORTED_7      INTEGER(11),
    REPORTED_8      INTEGER(11),
    REPORTED_9      INTEGER(11),
    REPORTED_10     INTEGER(11)
 );
```

and I need to sum by id.  I do this:

```
SELECT(ID, SUM)
        a.ID,
        (a.REPORTED_0 + a.REPORTED_2 + a.REPORTED_3 + a.REPORTED_4 +
        a.REPORTED_5 + a.REPORTED_6 + a.REPORTED_7 + a.REPORTED_8 +
        a.REPORTED_9 + a.REPORTED_10)
FROM EXAMPLE a
GROUP BY a.ID;
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this sum?

Sorry but I´m very noob with sql.

Comment: Why do you need grouping? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not really; aside from creating a table with ID, ReportedID & the reported values

Comment: It looks like the `GROUP BY` is unnecessary since you are adding up columns in the same row, unless you have multiple rows per ID.  But really this should be normalized out into another table rather than multiple reporting cols in this table.

Comment: I'm sure you know you didn't include REPORTED_1 in your sum. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your existing schema, there is nothing inefficient about your query. If you are looking for some syntactic shortcut to add up all but one column without naming the columns you won't find it. The `SUM()` function is used for summing rows, not columns.

Since you are selecting from a single table you don't need the table alias, and you missed one of the columns in your original query. Also your query won't handle NULLs very well. You probably want to treat them as 0. Here's a rewritten query that should do what you want:

```
SELECT ID,
  (
    COALESCE(REPORTED_0,0) + COALESCE(REPORTED_1,0) + COALESCE(REPORTED_2,0) + 
    COALESCE(REPORTED_3,0) + COALESCE(REPORTED_4,0) + COALESCE(REPORTED_5,0) + 
    COALESCE(REPORTED_6,0) + COALESCE(REPORTED_7,0) + COALESCE(REPORTED_8,0) + 
    COALESCE(REPORTED_9,0) + COALESCE(REPORTED_10,0)
  ) AS REPORTED_TOTAL
FROM EXAMPLE
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's only the most efficient solution. You have a very poor table structure. If I were you, you have to do the table's structure like this:

```
Create Table Example
(
    ID              BigInt(20),
    ReportValue     Int(11),
    ReportIndex     Int(5)
)
```

So this will be the query for the structure:

```
SELECT  ID, SUM(ReportValue)
From    Example
GROUP BY    ID
```

Well, it's only a suggestion :)